# For equation $A\cdot x=0$, what conditions on matrix $A$ will ensure that $x$ is not a positive or negative vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix and $x$ be a $n\times 1$ vector. Consider equation $A\times x=0$.

Under what conditions, $x$ is not a positive or negative vector? That is, we cannot have all entries of $x$ are positive or all are negative.

I guess it's about the eigenvalues of $A^TA$. Perhaps, they can't be all positive or all negative? This is just my guess and I have been alway from linear algebra for a long time. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: So you're basically asking for conditions on $A$ such that its kernel does not intersect the set $\mathbb R^n_+ \cup \mathbb R^n_-$ where $\mathbb R_+ := (0,\infty); \mathbb R_- := (-\infty, 0)$, right?

Comment: @AlexR Well...I don't remember what is kernel but I just googled it. I think you are right.

Comment: First off, you can ignore the negative part. If $Ax=0$, so is $A(-x)$, wich means it suffices to have no intersection with $\mathbb R_+^n$.

Comment: (On your last paragraph): For real matrices $A$, the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are always nonnegative.

Comment: @AlexR Thanks for your reminding. I just googled kernel and I saw on wiki that there is a constructive way, called Gaussian elimination to compute the basis of the kernel. So ideally given any matrix $A$, I can use computer program to figure out if $x$ can or cannot be positive, right? I just wonder if there exists a general condition on $A$ which is easily tested.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for reminding! My guess is completely wrong.

Comment: I mean, there is an obvious condition: if at least one row of $A$ has entries of the same sign (and at least one nonzero) then $Ax=0$ implies $x$ is not a positive vector. Of course, its not equivalent to the statement.

Comment: Another obvious condition is if the columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @Micheal yes. And in these terms we really ask if their nonzero convex combinations contain $0$. But I can't think of a simple way to check it .

Comment: If you have a Basis for the kernel, it's just a matter of finding or disproving the existence of a positive vector in the span of the basis.

Comment: What is the context here?  Is this a homework problem? I believe this is equivalent to checking if $Col(A^T)$ contains an all-positive.

Comment: @ПетяНарышкин You were actually very close. The condition is sufficient if you allow for a linear combination of the rows too.

Answer (score 1):

The absence of a positive (and negaitve) solutions to $Ax=0$ can be approached via convex duality where it is equivalent to the existing of a solution to the dual system of (in this case linear) constraints. Namely, one can use [Farkas lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma).

We want the following system
$$
Ax=0,x>0
$$
to have no solution. Introducing the notation $e$ for the vector of all ones
$$
e=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
the system may equivalently be rewritten as the second alternative in the link above
$$
\begin{cases}
Ax\ge 0,\\
-Ax\ge 0,\\
x\ge t\cdot e,\\
t>0
\end{cases}
\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad
\begin{cases}
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\-A & 0\\I & -e
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\t\end{bmatrix}\ge 0,\\
\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\t\end{bmatrix}<0.
\end{cases}
$$
Here zero blocks are columns/rows of corresponding dimensions to fit the block matrix.

Farkas lemma gives then the necessary and sufficient condition as that there exists a solution to the dual (first) alternative in the link
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{bmatrix}
A^T & -A^T & I\\0 & 0 & -e^T
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\end{bmatrix},\\u,v,w\ge 0
\end{cases}\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad
\begin{cases}
A^T(v-u)=w,\\
e^Tw=1,\\
u,v,w\ge 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Introducing the notation $d=v-u$ we get rid of the positivity condition (the standard procedure in the linear programming), and the system becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
A^Td=w\ge 0,\\
e^Tw=1.
\end{cases}
$$
The last condition is the normalization which is equivalent to saying that $w\ne 0$ (because then we can always scale the solution by $e^Tw$). Therefore we arrive to the equivalent condition that

> there must exist a solution to the following system
>   $$
> A^Td\ge 0,\quad A^Td\ne 0.
> $$

**Interpretaion:** it is the same as $d^TA\ge 0,\ne 0$, that is, there exists a linear combination of the rows of $A$ that is nonnegative and nonzero. It is easy to see that it is necessary (see the comment from Петя Нарышкин): $Ax=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\underbrace{d^TA}_{\ge 0,\ne 0}x=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $x\not> 0$.

A test for that can be implemented e.g. as LP
$$
\gamma=\max_{d,w} e^Tw\quad\text{ subject to }A^Td=w,\ w\ge 0,\ -1\le d_i\le 1.
$$
If $\gamma>0$ then it is ok.